# Are there any risks/downsides to putting emojis in code?

Tags: python, emoji

I sometimes use emojis in programs to highlight certain parts of the code (in open source libraries). I rarely use more than say 5-6 per script and I find they really stand out due to their colors in a text editor.

Typically, they are transient markers and will be removed when whatever issue they are associated with is closed.

My question is:  are emojis liable to cause any issues in the general Python toolchain?  This includes, but is not limited to:  git, github, pypi, editors, linters, interpreter, CI/CD pipelines, command line usage...

I haven't seen any, but then again I rarely see emojis in code.  This is a Python 3 only question, so Python 2 unicode aspects are out.

(This question is not about whether this *looks professional* or not.  That's a valid, but entirely separate consideration.)

#### Some examples:

```
# ⚙️ this is where you configure foo
foo.max_cntr = 10
foo.tolerate_duplicates = False

# ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️ to indicate code to be removed
some dead code

#  very important, don't forget to do this!
bar.deactivate_before_call()
```

Comment: Some Linux distributions do not have a default emoji font installed so the emojis could be displayed as one generic "fallback symbol" for some folks. I myself use Linux Mint, where the default emoji font is only black and white emojis so your stated advantage of "standing out due to their colors" would not be true for those people.

Comment: @DerBen It sounds like this is just for his personal use, so he might not care how they look to others. He's just concerned whether something will break.

Comment: @Barmar  actually, DerBen's warning is precisely the type of things I'd want to keep in mind.  Open source libraries are meant to be shared.

Comment: An Emoji is simply a Unicode character, and so far as I know there are no toolchain issues with Unicode.

Comment: Neither a purely technical issue nor one of professionalism: I (as a perhaps-representative member of the community) am not going to try to type those if I contribute to your project, so your consistency is likely to suffer in ways that `# FIXME` (plus editor configuration) will not.

Comment: I use emoticons with the `logging` module to quickly identify visually the type of event. I never encountered any problem.

Comment: Assuming that you want emoji's in text the users see (not just source code comments), you could register a custom error handler with the codec module which replaces emoji's not installed on the user's system with an ascii emoji from a dictionary. But if all you're talking about is putting them in code comments, then yeah.. that would be kind of annoying =/ to deal with for me personally if I had to use those sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of risks, there aren't really any real ones. If you use them in comments they'll be removed/ignored at runtime anyway so performance-wise there's no issues.

The main issue that you could run into is that some Linux distributions (distros) **DONT** support emojis, so they'd fallback to some standard unicode character (generically a white rectangle with a cross through the middle), so this could make comments hard to understand.

But in personal use: no not really, there's no issues.

**TLDR**: Probably not, but maybe.